# Seamlessly texture a cylinder with OpenGL and LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I am working on creating a procedural city, complete with randomly generated buildings and textures. I am generating cylinder-ish buildings correctly, and generating a procedural texture pattern for windows, but when I map the texture onto the cylinder it doesn't come out how I think it should.

[image]

The picture shows my three problems.
Firstly, my cylinder code will randomly skip 90 degrees to create slices out of the cylinder that look nice, and when two of these happen the second one has the stretches texture that you see here. The first slice looks perfectly fine. That is number 2 on the image.

The second problem--numbered 1--is that for some reason it appears to take a large section of the texture and map it onto a small slice at the end of the cylinder, and this happens every time.

The third problem is slightly harder to notice, although it is easiest to see on number 1, if you look at the top, the texture is much wider than is it at the bottom, and I don't know why.

Here is my source code for creating and texturing the cylinder: http://pastebin.com/hgMhqScg

Here is the code that generates the textures and the code that stores and renders the actual vertices: http://pastebin.com/cUuEBmTr  http://pastebin.com/GrytFsf1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem for #1 was here:

```
 if(i < v2UVA.length-1)
```

Switch that to

```
 if(i < v2UVA.length)
```

And that problem goes away. Not sure why the stretching happens, but I just limited the max cuts to 1 and it works fine.